# Rspec reset database before each file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, unit-testing, rspec

I have some unit tests that only pass if I clean the database before run it.

But if I run all tests with rspec command they don't work anymore, and I don't know why.

So how I reset the tests database before each file?

I already try:

```
config.before(:suite) do
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end
config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Can you be more descriptive than " they don't work anymore"?

Comment: @ruby_newbie I have a filter that look for current user (user logged in), but the id is always growing up, so I guess the database is get some error

Comment: did you make sure to require this code in your test files?

Comment: " id is always growing up" I am not sure what you mean by this.  Can you please post an error or the difference between what is happening or what you expect to happen?  Also post your test, and the spec_helper contents.